# Im trying to connect to a FTP server and retrieve a file but getting this error(503 bad sequence of commands)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Anyone who has an idea how to make this work?im trying to connect and check if the server is available for posible download.

```
    Protected Function Check_FTPServerAccessable(Dir_User As String, Dir_Passw As String) As Boolean
    Check_FTPServerAccessable = False        
    Dim Dir_tpWebRequest As FtpWebRequest
    Dim Dir_tpWebResponse As FtpWebResponse

    Dir_tpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("ftp://130.100.100.100/outbound/indexfile")

    Dim cc As New CredentialCache()
    cc.Add(New Uri("http://intranet/"), "NTLM", New NetworkCredential(Dir_User, Dir_Passw, "domain"))
    Dir_tpWebRequest.Credentials = cc
    '
    ' Conect to direrctory and retrive outbound index file for available downloads
    '
    Try
        Dir_tpWebResponse = Dir_tpWebRequest.GetResponse()'This code produces 503 Bad sequence of command
        Check_FTPServerAccessable = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        If Request.IsLocal Then
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("CurrentError") = ex.Message
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("sv_Ec") = "003"
        Else
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("CurrentError") = "Error processing page."
        End If

        Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx")

        Exit Function
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying and adapting this code:

```
' Get the object used to communicate with the server.  
Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://130.100.100.100/outbound/indexfile"), FtpWebRequest)
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
' This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.  
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Dir_User, Dir_Passw)
Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd())
Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription)
reader.Close()
response.Close()
```

Comment: "Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)" this line of code produce an error "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: @EdwardCalusayan did you check the adresse I put actually points to an existing file? or did you just copy paste?

Comment: it working already thanks. Is there another way for this code "request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Dir_User, Dir_Passw)" it detects as vulnerability authentication entity. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @EdwardCalusayan no idea about that. maybe try to use SFTP instead of normal FTP

Comment: do you have a sample of SFTP